# MySQL Error - Not sure whats wrong with SQL Command

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE Sponsors (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Sponsor_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Runner_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Charity_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Subscription_Id` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Customer_Id` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Customer_Email` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `APM` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `MinAPM` int(11) DEFAULT '5',
  `MaxAPM` int(11) DEFAULT '100',
  `Created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CharityId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CharityName` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `CharityCity` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `CharityState` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `CharityCategory` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `Total_Donations` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Monthly_Donations` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Distance` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE Sponsors (

'Id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'Sponsor_Id'

Comment: I'd guess you're trying to run a dump file using an API that doesn't support multi-query.

Comment: You will also find that using straight single quotes won't work to delimit column names. Straight quotes are for string literals or date literals. Back-ticks are for delimiting identifiers like table names or column names.

Comment: just replaced the single quotes with back-ticks and still nothing.  You are correct that this is a dump file.  Exporting from one DB to another...

Comment: How are you running the dump file?

Comment: Are you running this as php? The comments under the answer you accepted suggests it. I also feel that you accepted the answer "just cuz". You state that there was already code used in yours and what the answer holds seem to contradict everything. @CorrieByrd

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Sponsors (
  `Id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `Sponsor_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Runner_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Charity_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    primary key (id)
)
```

Comment: primary key was at the bottom of the full code. i just added the rest of it.

Comment: no, it was always there, i just failed to post it here.

Comment: what mysql version are you using?

Comment: Also try running my answer as a query and let me know if you are getting any errors

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.5

Comment: nevermind....running it as query works...importing it from the SQL file is not....

Comment: yeah...thank you very much. i was beating my head against a wall.

Comment: ok great, so please can you mark this as the correct answer for other users to use as a reference